# Java RegEx SubString Between multiple lines

Tags: java, regex, substring

I am having contents like following.

```
c\cert\ "test1" text
--Begin Cert
cert content1
cert content 2
--End Cert

c\cert\ "testCert2" text
--Begin Cert
cert test content1
cert test content 2
--End Cert

c\cert\ "sampleCert2" text
--Begin Cert
sample content1
sample test content 2
--End Cert
```

I need to extract contents and save in a map like

```
Key:test1
value:"--Begin Cert
    cert content1
    cert content 2
    --End Cert"
Key:testCert2
value:"--Begin Cert
    cert test content1
    cert test content 2
    --End Cert"
. 
.
etc
```

I Can do with looping line by line . But I want to do it with RegEx.
This is what I have tried .

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?m)^c\\\\cert\\\\ \"(\\w++)\" text\r?\n(.*?)\\s*$").matcher(configContent)
while (m.find()) {
map.put(m.group(1),m.group(2));
}
```

But I am not getting the output as expected . Please help me in forming correct Regex.

Comment: To match a backslash, you need 4 backslashes in a regex string - ``\\\\``. And you can safely remove the second `^`, and replace the first `$` with `\r?\n`. And you forgot the quotation marks.

Comment: @stribizhev thanks for the corrections . I can get almost what I expected. But I am getting "--Begin Cert" only in m.group(2) .  I need to get as "--\nBegin Cert\ncert content1\ncert content 2\n --End Cert"

Comment: And you got an answer, I guess :)

Comment: @Ramesh the `.` character in regex doesn't include newline characters, have a look at this regex `((?:.+\\n)+(?:.+))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will do it:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^c\\\\cert\\\\ \"([^\"]+)\" text\r?\n" +
                            "(--Begin Cert\r?\n.*?\r?\n--End Cert)[\r\n]*",
                            Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Key:" + m.group(1));
    System.out.println("value:\"" + m.group(2) + "\"");
    System.out.println();
}
```

Run with:

```
String input = "c\\cert\\ \"test1\" text\r\n" +
               "--Begin Cert\r\n" +
               "cert content1\r\n" +
               "cert content 2\r\n" +
               "--End Cert\r\n" +
               "\r\n" +
               "c\\cert\\ \"testCert2\" text\r\n" +
               "--Begin Cert\r\n" +
               "cert test content1\r\n" +
               "cert test content 2\r\n" +
               "--End Cert\r\n" +
               "\r\n" +
               "c\\cert\\ \"sampleCert2\" text\r\n" +
               "--Begin Cert\r\n" +
               "sample content1\r\n" +
               "sample test content 2\r\n" +
               "--End Cert\r\n";
```

And you get:

```
Key:test1
value:"--Begin Cert
cert content1
cert content 2
--End Cert"

Key:testCert2
value:"--Begin Cert
cert test content1
cert test content 2
--End Cert"

Key:sampleCert2
value:"--Begin Cert
sample content1
sample test content 2
--End Cert"
```

Change input to newlines only (`\n` instead of `\r\n`), and it'll still work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape all the `\`'s again because java strings, but also like stribizhev has said if you want to match a `\` then you need `\\` in regex but a `\\\\` in java regex.

You might want something more like this:

`(?m)c\\\\cert\\\\\\s"(\\w++)"\\stext\\s((?:.+\\n)+(?:.+))`

So this part `(?m)c\\\\cert\\\\\\s"(\\w++)"\\stext\\s` gets whats in the quotes, mostly your stuff just java-ified

And this bit
`((?:.+\\n)+(?:.+))`
will catch any number of lines with at least 1 character